# VB Script can't run in Field Calculator

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, arcgis-10.2, vbscript, vb

I wrote a simple script in VB. But it failed to run in field calculator. I can't figure out what is wrong with it. Below is a screenshot.

[image]

Comment: I don't really know vbscript but that pipe character at after a="N" looks like it could be the culprit.

Comment: Thanks, Fezter! I tried, that was not the problem.

Comment: Is the field you're updating a text field?

Comment: Yes, it is. The data type of "Match", "HHZIP", and "ZCTA5CE10" are all text

Comment: Use Python!  :):D

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `Dim a as String` line and it will work. Calculate Field is using VBScript, and in VBScript all variables are of type Variant.